# Run a Function Upon Exiting a Terminal

Tags: neovim, lua

By using the following code...

```lua
vim.fn.termopen("foo")
```

I can open a terminal with a certain command. What I want to do is run a Lua function from a plugin upon exiting the terminal.

Pseudo Code:

```
vim.fn.termopen("foo", run "lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()" upon exiting)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I found that there are two autocommands I can use that suit my needs

```
au TermClose * lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()

or

au TermLeave * lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()
```

The first one works better for me because I only want to run my function once the terminal is killed/closed. The second one is for if you want to run a function once the user switches from the terminal to something else.

Answer (score 0):

In regular vim, the API would be `term_start()` with the `exit_cb` option set:

```
function Exit(job, exit_status) abort
  echom 'goodbye world'
endfunction
call term_start('echo hello world', #{exit_cb: 'Exit'})
```